# How to pass "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." when suggesting edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

When I edit somebody's question, I find there is a formatting problem, so I turn code block into code, but I can not pass this rule:

> "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Because the code is too long, even if I add more details, could not submit my edit.

Without any other choice, I had to give up my edits several times.

What's the best practice in this situation?

I know there are similiar questions about this, but I couldn't find the answer that I need.